# No sé como acceder a los elementos y/o atributos de una lista de python. La lista contiene elementos de PyQt (QFrames personalizados)

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
def agregarElemento(self):
     lista = []
     F = QtWidgets.QFrame()  
     ui = Ui_FrameImagen() #Mi clase personalizada     
     ui.setupUi(F)
     lista.append(F)
```

Ya intenté de muchas formas acceder a los elementos pero no se que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega todo lo que has intentado :D

Comment: Es una lista, no tiene nada de especial que contenga QFrames, es un objeto como cualquier otro. `F[0]` te da una referencia al primer `QFrame` de la lista, `F[1]` al segunto, etc.... o itera con un for: `for frame in lista: frame.metodo_del_frame()` Ahora bien, lista es una variable local, dejará de existir en cuanto `agregarElemento` retorne. Si necesitas usarla fuera haz que sea un atributo de instancia, `self.lista_frames = []`.... Deberías mostra como comenta fredyfx  lo que intentas hacer con la lista después y que no te funciona y muy importante, desde dónde y el error.

Comment: Gracias fredyfx de hecho, el codigo solo es una pequeña referencia, pero la realidad es que la lista esta desde el constructor y estoy intentando agregar elementos de otra clase para usarlos como una lista de paneles ensamblados, pero quiero acceder a sus elementos para poder tomar acciones.

Comment: Tenia un typo, arriba, sería `lista[0]` no `F[0]`... La construyas donde la construyas si la vas a usar fuera del `__init__` creala como atributo de instancia o en cuanto el inicializador retorne dejará de existir como comento. Dicho esto, el acceso al los QFrames es como comento arriba, o indizas o iteras no hay más.  Después puedes hacer por ejemplo, `lista[0].sizeHint()` y sería lo mismo que `F.sizeHint()`, sin ver exactamente que intentas hacer o el error no creo que podamos agregar mucho más.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo he solucionado, el problema radicaba en la manera en que yo estaba creando las clases que eran compiladas por pyuic5, pero hice una clase con herencia y con el constructor super() y se solucionó el acceso a los atributos. Muchas gracias por su ayuda